# As3 Flash: property of 3d mesh

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-cs5, away3d

Below i have purposely made a test script: you can see it live at [www.parele.com/plane.html](http://www.parele.com/plane.html)
All source code is below, what im trying to do is change my mesh...please note:i want to change material of my model mesh , to another color , any color not create a new plane as this sample is an example to test this out not my actual hobby project, any files or info needed im happy to supply..I have been at this for a full over 20 hours stuck here and its killing me

```
import away3d.containers.Scene3D;
import away3d.containers.View3D;
import away3d.containers.ObjectContainer3D;
import away3d.debug.AwayStats;
import away3d.entities.Mesh;
import away3d.containers.ObjectContainer3D;
import away3d.loaders.Loader3D;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import away3d.*;
import away3d.materials.ColorMaterial;
import away3d.materials.TextureMaterial;
import away3d.textures.BitmapTexture;
import sunag.animation.AnimationTarget;
import sunag.events.SEAEvent;
import sunag.sea3d.SEA3D;
import away3d.materials.methods.*;
import away3d.primitives.*;
import away3d.textures.*;
import away3d.utils.*;
import away3d.events.*;
[SWF(width = "955",height = "600",frameRate = "50")]
var view:View3D;
var scene:Scene3D;
var sea3d:SEA3D;
var _container:ObjectContainer3D = new ObjectContainer3D();
[Embed(source = "Models/plane.sea",mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
var homepage:Class;
stage.stageFocusRect = false;
stage.showDefaultContextMenu = false;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
scene = new Scene3D();
view = new View3D(scene);
view.backgroundColor = stage.color;
view.antiAlias = 4;
var dat:BitmapData = new BitmapData(256, 256, false, WHATEVERCOLOUR);
var mMaterial = new TextureMaterial(new BitmapTexture(dat));
scene.addChild(_container);
addChild(view);
sea3d = new SEA3D();
view.blendMode = BlendMode.NORMAL;
sea3d.addEventListener(SEAEvent.COMPLETE, onComplete);
sea3d.loadBytes(new homepage());

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
{

 var body1:Mesh = sea3d.getMesh("body");
 body1.material = mMaterial;
 view.render();
 }
 function onComplete(e:SEAEvent):void
 {
 view.camera = sea3d.getCamera("Camera001");
  stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
  scene.addChild(sea3d.container);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for: [SubMeshes](http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/away3d/entities/Mesh.html#subMeshes)

A mesh you pull from a model is usually made of at least on SubMesh, but can contain several. Changing the Material on that "root" Mesh object doesn't propagate to its SubMeshes. You need to iterate through its SubMeshes and change their material.

hth.